# How do I grant access to users to Azure SQL DB with no rights to create Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to have rights to my Azure SQL Server where I can read and access data and also add other AD users to access the DB but they should not be allowed to create any new database. I couldnt find any roles which does that...nor I am able to find a custom role in AD which does that. Can someone please specify step by step how can I configure this for my AD users?

Comment: Considering `USER`s are database objects, which you are very likely using here as you're using Azure SQL Database, then they would *not* be able to create another database anyway; that requires a `LOGIN`.

Comment: didnt get you..please can you elaborate..should I add Login as one of the rights for users..

Comment: `USER`s can't have permission to create database, they aren't server level objects. As you are using Azure SQL Database, you are creating `USER`s, not `LOGIN`s, as the databases are contained databases, no?

Comment: ok.. noob question but I guess not understanding here.. I have a database and I have a table there and now I want to add one of the Active Directory users to access my database,, How do I do it? Is it not possible through Access management and giving him an AD role which will allow him to access the database?

Comment: I assume by "AD" you mean your Azure Active Directory? You can find the documentation here: [Create contained users mapped to Azure AD identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities)

Comment: so every time we have to give access to an AD user we need to add them by running command "CREATE LOGIN...."

Comment: `CREATE LOGIN` <>`CREATE USER`. I feel like there is perhaps some other fundamental knowledge you're missing here, meaning that none of the dots are connecting. You might want to talk to your DBA first, so they can explain how Azure AD works with Azure SQL Databases, and how it works in your environment.

Comment: If you are still there.. I get what you meant.. but my scenario is I have multiple database and I would like the user to have access to all the database but they shouldnt be able to create any new database but they should be able to create logins. I cannot keep going to each database and keep adding them with same role. there should be a simpler way

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using Azure SQL Database. Perhaps you should be looking at an Azure SQL Server Managed Instance, then you could make use of the `model` system database.

Comment: I understood this is something to be managed at server instance.. Model system? Any link to that?

Comment: Not model system, model system database; it is a *system* database like `master`, `tempdb` and `msdb`, which (apart from `master`) are not available in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: so we cant actually have this kind of role definition for Azure SQL Db